# IOS Local Rich notification with image attachment: Avoid expanded

Tags: ios, notifications, push, local, richpush

I am working with local notifications on iOS (UserNotifications).
I attach an image in the content of the notification.
What I want to do is that the image does not show expanded on push (I need it to be hidden or it is just not possible to expand the notification).

it's possible? I just want the image to always display in thumbnail format, never expanded.

Best regards